# send session var with php cUrl

Tags: php, session, scripting, curl

Am trying to send data between scripts within my application.

Problem is session id is not responding.

Script 1 is...

```
 <?php 
      session_start();

      $_SESSION['id'] = 1;

      $data = "data to be sent to script";

      $ch = curl_init("http:.../myscript.php");

      $nvp = "&data=$data";

      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvp);

      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

      echo curl_exec($ch);

      ?>
```

myScript.php is...

```
      <?php

      session_start();          

      $id = $_SESSION['id'];

      $data = $_POST['data'];

      $result = function idData($id, $data); // returns matching results.


      echo "Session Id = $id <br />";


      echo "Id result = $result <br />";

      ?>
```

However myScript.php is not able to access the session data as per normal.

Is there a work around for this? What could the possible cause be?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In script 1 you could use `CURLOPT_COOKIE` if you keep track of the session ID from the response yourself.

I don't think you need or want session_start in script 1 if it is going to be making multiple requests to myscript.php that creates a session.

Use this in script 1:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/tmp/cookies.txt'); // set cookie file to given file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/cookies.txt'); // set same file as cookie jar
```

And then make your request as normal.  Any cookies set by myscript.php will be saved to the cookie jar file when the request completes, the cookiefile will be checked for any cookies to be sent prior to sending the request.

You could manually track the php session cookie from the curl request and use `CURLOPT_COOKIE` as well.

Answer (score 9):

I believe you're looking for [CURLOPT_COOKIE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, session_name() . '=' . session_id());
```

Comment: I get what your getting at but does the session Id need to be caught as anything in particular on the other side??

Comment: Ya I have it dosent work... i read up on the function library still pretty confused as im new to cURL... when I send it from the original script to myscript.php the server ceases to respond... and just sat there 'waiting for local host...'. Do I need to attach a cookie file for the server to reference?? or could I reference the session name and id as $_POST variables?

Comment: @Christopher the server (myScript.php) waits for the session cookie file resources, as concurrent session access is not allowed. To solve it, use `session_write_close()` before curl_exec and `session_start()` again after curl_exec returns the response.

Answer (score -2):

You miss one option parameter for using post. Please add this one, it should work:
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);`