# Curl cant set laravel session cookie

Tags: php, laravel, curl, cookies

I need to call internally(with content) in laravel

```
public function callingFunction(Request $request) {
  //login user
  $this->getSession('MY_USER_LOGIN');

  $userId = \Auth::id();
  //logged userid is available - ok

  //call another controller
  $curl = curl_init('another_addres_on_server_for_callTo_function');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);

  $laravel_cookie = $request->cookie('laravel_session');
  //cookie is available - OK

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "laravel_session=".$laravel_cookie);
  $response = curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close($curl);
}
```

I call to

```
public function callTo() {
  $laravel_cookie = $request->cookie('laravel_session');
  //cookie is available - OK
  $userId = \Auth::id();
  //userId is null - NOT OK but why if cookie is available
}
```

I cant get session after call curl.
Can anybody tell Me how to modify curl to get session on other side?

php -v
PHP 7.3.27-1~deb10u1 (cli) (built: Feb 13 2021 16:31:40) ( NTS )

Comment: Specify files for cURL to write cookies to, and read them back for the next request. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7508932/1427878

Comment: callingFunction is tool to call 900 different catllTo functions. I cant change all callTo functions in easy way. this->getSession is laravel authorization Auth::loginUsingId($userId);.